# COLLECT STATS is not getting the real values

Tags: teradata

I have this table in Teradata (15.00)

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE STG_DB.TB_LINES (
  COD_ORDER VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,   
  NUM_LINE DECIMAL(4,0) NOT NULL
) PRIMARY INDEX TB_LINES_NUPI ( COD_ORDER );
```

And this is how I collect stats:

```
COLLECT STATISTICS 
            COLUMN ( COD_ORDER  ) , 
            COLUMN ( COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE  ) 
                ON STG_DB.TB_LINES ;
```

But when I do a HELP STATS ON STG_DB.TB_LINES; I get the following results:

```
Unique Values,   Column Names
    5,531,048,   *
    3,403,375,   COD_ORDER
       72,097,   COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE
```

**Why am I getting 72,097 in the (COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE) pair?**

The unique value for COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE should be 5,531,048 because NUM_LINE is a sequence I give starting at 1 for every COD_ORDER.

At the very worst, (COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE) should have the same values as (COD_ORDER), shouldn't it?

I have tried adding USING SAMPLE 100 PERCENT with no better output.

**How can I get the real full stats on the table?** The same values as when I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM ( 
SELECT COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE 
  FROM STG_DB.TB_LINES 
 GROUP BY 1,2 ) D1;
```

Thanks in advance :)

---

Edit: Checking the stats values with:

```
SHOW STATISTICS VALUES COLUMN ( COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE ) ON STG_DB.TB_LINES;
```

I have seen that my ORDER values were getting truncated to 26 chars and then I have seen this option into the *SQL Data Definition Language - Syntax and Examples.pdf*:

> **MAXVALUELENGTH n**
>   Specifies the maximum size for histogram values such as MinValue, ModeValue, MaxValue, and so on, where n is an integer.
>   For single-character statistics on CHARACTER and VARCHAR columns, n specifies the number of characters. For all other options, n specifies number of bytes.
>   You can only specify this option if you also specify an explicit index or column set.
>   You cannot use this option to collect statistics on a geospatial NUSI.
>   This option is valid only for tables.

So doing the following solved the issue:

```
COLLECT STATISTICS 
             USING MAXVALUELENGTH 60 -- length of my COD_ORDER field
            COLUMN ( COD_ORDER  ) , 
            COLUMN ( COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE  ) 
                ON STG_DB.TB_LINES ;
```

Thanks for your time :)

---

Edit2: Adding the stat values:

```
COLLECT STATISTICS 
            COLUMN ( COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE  ) 
                ON STG_DB.TB_LINES 
            VALUES
(
 /** SummaryInfo **/ 
 /* Data Type and Length: 'CV:26', 'D:0:4:0' */
 /* TimeStamp             */ TIMESTAMP '2018-09-03 11:33:16-00:00', 
 /* Version               */ 6, 
 /* OriginalVersion       */ 6, 
 /* DBSVersion            */ '15.00.06.13', 
 /* UsageType             */ 'D', 
 /* ComplexStatInfo       */ 'ComplexStatInfo', 
 /* NumOfBiasedValues     */ 144, 
 /* NumOfEHIntervals      */ 1, 
 /* NumOfHistoryRecords   */ 0, 
 /* SamplePercent         */ 0.00, 
 /* NumOfNulls            */ 0, 
 /* NumOfAllNulls         */ 0, 
 /* NumOfPartialNullVals  */ 0, 
 /* PartialNullHMF        */ 0, 
 /* AvgAmpRPV             */ 0.000000, 
 /* MinVal                */ 'ID:414d5120514d50524f30312', 0., 
 /* MaxVal                */ 'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 
 /* ModeVal               */ 'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 
 /* HighModeFreq          */ 36405, 
 /* NumOfDistinctVals     */ 72097, 
 /* NumOfRows             */ 6037117, 
 /* CPUUsage              */ 0.000000, 
 /* IOUsage               */ 0.000000, 
 /* Reserved              */ 0, 
 /* Reserved              */ 0, 
 /* Reserved              */ 0.000000, 
 /* Reserved              */ 0.000000, 
 /* Reserved              */ 'T0000D00000S00000', 
 /* StatsSkipCount        */ 0, 
 /* SysInsertCnt          */ 0, 
 /* SysDeleteCnt          */ 0, 
 /* SysUpdateCnt          */ 0, 
 /* SysInsDelLastResetTS  */ TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 23:59:59-00:00', 
 /* SysUpdLastResetTS     */ TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 23:59:59-00:00', 
 /* IsSampleFollowingTrend*/ 0, 
 /** Biased: Value[2], Frequency **/ 
 /*   1 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18103, 
 /*   2 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18110, 
 /*   3 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17983, 
 /*   4 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18018, 
 /*   5 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18058, 
 /*   6 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17943, 
 /*   7 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17994, 
 /*   8 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18166, 
 /*   9 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18040, 
 /*  10 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18062, 
 /*  11 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18299, 
 /*  12 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18128, 
 /*  13 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17890, 
 /*  14 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18422, 
 /*  15 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18108, 
 /*  16 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18223, 
 /*  17 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18033, 
 /*  18 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18213, 
 /*  19 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17992, 
 /*  20 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18225, 
 /*  21 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18157, 
 /*  22 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18207, 
 /*  23 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18436, 
 /*  24 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18141, 
 /*  25 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18172, 
 /*  26 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18241, 
 /*  27 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18111, 
 /*  28 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17898, 
 /*  29 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18201, 
 /*  30 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18071, 
 /*  31 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17888, 
 /*  32 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18035, 
 /*  33 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18252, 
 /*  34 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18059, 
 /*  35 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18187, 
 /*  36 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18150, 
 /*  37 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18173, 
 /*  38 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18026, 
 /*  39 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18450, 
 /*  40 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18330, 
 /*  41 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18227, 
 /*  42 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17953, 
 /*  43 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18361, 
 /*  44 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18176, 
 /*  45 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18027, 
 /*  46 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18041, 
 /*  47 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17983, 
 /*  48 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18095, 
 /*  49 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18131, 
 /*  50 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18334, 
 /*  51 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18084, 
 /*  52 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17901, 
 /*  53 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18139, 
 /*  54 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18311, 
 /*  55 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18046, 
 /*  56 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17992, 
 /*  57 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17977, 
 /*  58 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18220, 
 /*  59 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18179, 
 /*  60 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18171, 
 /*  61 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17895, 
 /*  62 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18270, 
 /*  63 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18146, 
 /*  64 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18248, 
 /*  65 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 17901, 
 /*  66 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18202, 
 /*  67 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18391, 
 /*  68 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18173, 
 /*  69 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18204, 
 /*  70 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18164, 
 /*  71 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18233, 
 /*  72 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 18195, 
 /*  73 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35659, 
 /*  74 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36011, 
 /*  75 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35582, 
 /*  76 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36139, 
 /*  77 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36271, 
 /*  78 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36069, 
 /*  79 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36032, 
 /*  80 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35960, 
 /*  81 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36128, 
 /*  82 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35982, 
 /*  83 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35960, 
 /*  84 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36081, 
 /*  85 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35812, 
 /*  86 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35858, 
 /*  87 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35844, 
 /*  88 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36212, 
 /*  89 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35803, 
 /*  90 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36057, 
 /*  91 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36405, 
 /*  92 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35983, 
 /*  93 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35898, 
 /*  94 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36200, 
 /*  95 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35650, 
 /*  96 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35718, 
 /*  97 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35952, 
 /*  98 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35979, 
 /*  99 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35720, 
 /* 100 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36012, 
 /* 101 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35974, 
 /* 102 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36095, 
 /* 103 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35500, 
 /* 104 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35932, 
 /* 105 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36208, 
 /* 106 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35794, 
 /* 107 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35882, 
 /* 108 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35860, 
 /* 109 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36046, 
 /* 110 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35880, 
 /* 111 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35890, 
 /* 112 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36121, 
 /* 113 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36002, 
 /* 114 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35618, 
 /* 115 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35768, 
 /* 116 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36022, 
 /* 117 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35812, 
 /* 118 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36246, 
 /* 119 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36189, 
 /* 120 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35994, 
 /* 121 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36035, 
 /* 122 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35618, 
 /* 123 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35908, 
 /* 124 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35567, 
 /* 125 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35775, 
 /* 126 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35922, 
 /* 127 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35865, 
 /* 128 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36027, 
 /* 129 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35854, 
 /* 130 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35926, 
 /* 131 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35951, 
 /* 132 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36256, 
 /* 133 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35591, 
 /* 134 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35822, 
 /* 135 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35900, 
 /* 136 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36265, 
 /* 137 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36109, 
 /* 138 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35881, 
 /* 139 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35411, 
 /* 140 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36192, 
 /* 141 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35926, 
 /* 142 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35919, 
 /* 143 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 36026, 
 /* 144 */   'ID:414d5120514d53474945505', 0., 35811, 
 /** Interval: MaxVal[2], ModeVal[2], ModeFreq, LowFreq, OtherVals, OtherRows **/ 
 /*     1   */ 'ID:414d5120514d50524f30312', 0., 'ID:414d5120514d50524f30312', 0., 68, 1, 71952, 2144117
);
```

Comment: For tbis column combination you don't need full stats (in fact I wouldn't collect it at all, because it not much more unique than `cod_order`), a small sample should be enough. Can you post the *SummaryInfo* returned by `SHOW STATS VALUES COLUMN ( COD_ORDER,NUM_LINE  ) 
                ON STG_DB.TB_LINES`? At least *SamplePercent, ModeVal, HighModeFreq, NumOfDistinctVals, NumOfRows*?

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, this table was only an example with the basic information. The real table has more fields. Using the MAXVALUELENGTH solved the issue.

Comment: Seems you store some kind of GUIDs, but even when the values stored in stats are truncated (which is known behaviour) the number of distinct values should be as you expected. The aggregation is done first without truncation, it's only truncated when stored in the stats.I just tried it on a 16.20 and the estimate was correct, maybe this was different in 15.10?

Comment: The unique values number for the field COD_ORDER alone was correct, but when I combined it with another field, I had the values truncated.